# JavaScript doesn't return value

Tags: javascript

I have some simple code that returns whether I'm scrolling up or down. I want to use it as a function with `return`, like this:

```
var scripts = {
getScrollDirection: function() {
    var dir;
    $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
            dir = 'up';
        } else {
            dir = 'down';
        }
    });
    return dir;
}
}
```

When I call `scripts.getScrollDirection`, I get undefined. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Setting up and event handler doesn't mean the code inside is going to run, so `dir` will stay undefined. Maybe you want to place the code for the function in `mousewheel DOMMouseScroll`?

Comment: are your codes in different js files? or located at different parts of the html document?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek it's odd since I used similar statements before. When I add `console.log` inside the `if/else` statements, it works. I really want to avoid placing function inside `mousewheel` event.

Comment: @Ji_in_coding it's all in one file.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski It is not odd at all, because you have two different functions that are called at different times.  Inside the callback (and after it is called) you set a value to `dir`.  Outside the callback, and before it is called, you have not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `dir`, and it is automatically initialized to `undefined`.
Then you registered a function as an event handler.
Then you returned the value of `dir`, which is still `undefined` because no value has been assigned to it.

---

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming

http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs168/f12/handouts/async.pdf

http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/theory/6040-what-is-asynchronous-programming.html

Comment: You're right, I forgot that it will change after an event. Thanks for this!